# SQL Exists Returns more records than IN

Tags: sql-server, exists

I'm running two queries for comparison:

```
SELECT 
    PD.PRACTITIONERID, PD.LastName, PD.FirstName, PD.NationalProviderID
FROM 
    vwPractitionerDemographics PD
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vwPractitionerLocations
            WHERE PracticeTaxIDNumber = '59-1205165')

SELECT  
    PD.PRACTITIONERID, PD.LastName, PD.FirstName, PD.NationalProviderID
FROM 
    vwPractitionerDemographics PD
WHERE 
    PRACTITIONERID IN (SELECT practitionerID FROM vwPractitionerLocations
                       WHERE PracticeTaxIDNumber = '59-1205165')
```

The query with the `EXISTS` clause returns 11,000 records, including those that do not have the filtered `PracticeTaxIDNumber`. The query with the `IN` clause returns 169 records, and produces the correct result.

Can someone explain why the `EXISTS` does not work here?

I understand that `EXISTS` returns records if the condition is true, but since the condition is filtered with the `PracticeTaxIDNumber` I thought it would only return the filtered records.

Comment: Every record in `vbPractionerDemographics` table runs the `EXISTS` query seperately. That `PracticeTaxIDNumber` always manages to exist (how could it not) in your `vwPRactionerLocations` table and therefore every record is returned.

Comment: As for your IN, there are only 169 records in your `Demo` table where the `PractionerId` has a `PracticeTaxIDNumber` of `59-1205165`.

Comment: `EXIST` runs for every record, and evaluates to `true` if the query inside returns anything. `SELECT 1 FROM vwPractitionerLocations
    WHERE PracticeTaxIDNumber = '59-1205165'` will return true for *every record* of `vwPractitionerDemographics`, because that query will *always* return at least one result.

Comment: Are you saying that the Exists just evaluates whether the condition is true?  I.e., if a record does exist where PracticeTaxIDNumber = xxx, then run the main query--that the Exists query is actually independent of the main query.  If Exists is True, then run the main query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a JOIN or use EXISTS with a join in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT PD.PRACTITIONERID, PD.LastName, PD.FirstName, PD.NationalProviderID
FROM vwPractitionerDemographics PD
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 
    FROM vwPractitionerLocations
    WHERE PracticeTaxIDNumber = '59-1205165'
    AND vwPractitionerLocations.[matching column here] = PD.[matching column here])
```

```
SELECT PD.PRACTITIONERID, PD.LastName, PD.FirstName, PD.NationalProviderID
FROM vwPractitionerDemographics PD INNER JOIN vwPractitionerLocations ON vwPractitionerLocations.[matching column here] = PD.[matching column here])
WHERE PracticeTaxIDNumber = '59-1205165'
```

SQL Server cannot guess as to how you want the tables to relate to each other in the query, you have to supply that information explicitly. The use of `IN`, in this case`, was not correct as it should be used when evaluating multiple values. In your case you are passing a single value to be evaluated. If you really want to use IN then you would write`...WHERE PracticeTaxIDNumber IN ('59-1205165')` but I think you can see that this does not make much sense for 1 value.

Comment: Totally got it now.  Thank you!